# PrimeNG - p-dataTable height set by number of rows

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I'm trying to find a solution to fix the dataTable height.

The table has pagination added. Changing the page to the second page where the number of rows are lower as on initial page (in our case first page) the dataTable height will be changed.

Comment: I'm too facing the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Not yet. I added the DataTable inside a Panel. In this way, if the DataTable height is changed on pagination, the other components from the page are not moved.

Comment: I did add dummy rows to get the height.

Answer (score 8):

For me it worked with the following css statement:

```
::ng-deep .ui-datatable-scrollable-view .ui-datatable-scrollable-body {
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
```

::ng-deep targets *inside* the primeNg element < p-dataTable > . The min-height: 0px of the **ui-datatable-scrollable-body** class will be **overwritten** by your desired min-height.

Two css selectors are used instead of one to increase the css selector's specificity.

I created the following plunker that illustrates how it works.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8cFrCY?p=preview

Comment: It seems for me is not working. Can I ask you to post your example, everything you have regarding with dataTable?

Comment: Added a plunker example in the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also added dummy rows as mentioned earlier, but when I used globalfilter of primeng then the problem reoccurred so the fix for that is provided as follows :

I have two functions addRecordsForPagination and removeFunc in my component.ts

datatable is the viewchild for primeng table.

```
ngOnInit(){
  if(this.primengtable.length%10!=0)
        while(this.primengtable.length%10!=0)
  this.primengtable.push({});
}
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".ui-paginator-page.ui-paginator-element.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all")).filter(element => {

    if(element.getAttribute("listener")!="true")
    element.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
      element.setAttribute("listener","true");
     this.addRecordsForPagination();
     this.removeFunc();
    })
  });
} addRecordsForPagination=()=>{
let rows = this.dataTable.tableViewChild.nativeElement.children[2].children.length;

 if(rows==10)
 setTimeout(()=>{},0);

  if(this.dataTable.filteredValue)
  if(rows<10)
  for(let i=0;i<10-rows;i++){
    let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
    var thcount =  document.querySelectorAll('thead > tr > th').length;
    for(let i=0;i<thcount;i++)
    tableRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="&#127;";
 this.dataTable.tableViewChild.nativeElement.children[2].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',tableRow);

}


}removeFunc = ()=>{

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).filter((tr)=>{
//this is specific case in my grid
  if(tr.childNodes.length<10)
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);

  });​
}ngAfterViewChecked(): void { 

if(this.dataTable.tableViewChild)
var rows = this.dataTable.tableViewChild.nativeElement.children[2].children.length;
if(rows>10)
this.removeFunc();
this.addRecordsForPagination();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Primeng p-table, I set the min-height in styles.scss and it solved a similar issue.

```
.your_table_name .ui-table-scrollable-body  {
  min-height: 300px !important;
}
```